# Using NSGlyph and memory allocation

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nstextview, nslayoutmanager

in a method to track line breaks *frequently*, for a **NSTextView** `visibleRect`, i am allocating memory for **NSGlyph** to use **NSLayoutManager** `getGlyphs:range:`.

should/can i find out how much memory this should be since i have a reference for the range (without affecting layout), and also, what kind of cleanup should happen -- running with **ARC** ?

the code (which runs on a main queue) :

```
    NSLayoutManager *lm = [self.textView layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *tc = [self.textView textContainer];
    NSRect vRect = [self.textView visibleRect];
    NSRange visibleRange = [lm glyphRangeForBoundingRectWithoutAdditionalLayout:vRect inTextContainer:tc];
    NSUInteger vRangeLoc = visibleRange.location;
    NSUInteger numberOfLines;
    NSUInteger index;
    NSGlyph glyphArray[5000]; // <--- memory assigned here
    NSUInteger numberOfGlyphs = [lm getGlyphs:glyphArray range:visibleRange];
    NSRange lineRange;
    NSMutableIndexSet *idxset = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++) {
        (void)[lm lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index effectiveRange:&lineRange withoutAdditionalLayout:YES];
        [idxset addIndex:lineRange.location + vRangeLoc];
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }
    self.currentLinesIndexSet = idxset;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `NSGlyph glyphs[5000]` notation, you're allocating the memory on the stack. But instead of 5000 glyphs it only has to hold `visibleRange.length + 1` glyphs:

> ***glyphArray***
>
> On output, the displayable glyphs from *glyphRange*,
>   null-terminated. Does not include in the result any `NSNullGlyph` or
>   other glyphs that are not shown. The memory passed in should be large
>   enough for at least `glyphRange.length+1` elements.

And because it is on the stack, you don't have to worry about freeing the memory—because never malloced memory; it is freed automatically when leaving the function—even without **ARC**

So it should work, if you write it like this:

```
NSLayoutManager *lm = ...
NSRange glyphRange = ...
NSGlyph glyphArray[glyphRange.length + 1];
NSUInteger numberOfGlyphs = [lm getGlyphs:glyphArray range:glyphRange];
// do something with your glyphs
```

Comment: This is more precise:     NSGlyph    *glyphs = (NSGlyph *) malloc(sizeof(NSGlyph) * (visibleRange.length * 2));

...then use it then...

free(glyphs);

Comment: @johnrubythecat Why do you take the length twice?